# iOS AutoLayout: Constrain autolayout anchor to max or min value of two other anchors

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, linear-programming

While creating autolayout constraints, a frequent desire I have is to constrain an anchor of an `UIView` to the higher (or lower) valued of two other anchors.

An example of a constraint I wish to express to the autolayout engine is shown by the following GIF. In this instance, I constrain the width of rectangle C to be the max of the widths of rectangle A and rectangle B. So if I change the widths of rectange A and B, rectangle C scales accordingly.

[image: Autolayout]

Currently, it seems that the only method I am aware of is to say:

- width of rectangle C must be greater than or equal to width of rectangle A
- width of rectangle C must be greater than or equal to width of rectangle B

However, that approach has the significant problem of making the width of rectangle C ambiguous (since neither constraint above are "precise" constraints).

Now, before you say that there's no way for autolayout to have this, I would like to note that autolayout, to be my knowledge is just a linear optimizer. Min and Max constraints are a standard thing you can specify to a linear optimizer.

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply **multiples** of the same constraint, provided they don't conflict with each other. In this case, you **must** do so.

- RectC: Equal Width to RectA with `Priority: 750 (High)`
- RectC: Equal Width to RectB with `Priority: 750 (High)`
- RectC: GreaterThanOrEqual Width to RectA with `Priority: 1000 (Required)`
- RectC: GreaterThanOrEqual Width to RectB with `Priority: 1000 (Required)`

So, suppose RectA has a width of 200 and RectB has a width of 120...

Auto-layout will tell RectC's width to be:

- Step 1 ... equal to A (200)
- Step 2 ... equal to B (120)
- Step 3 ... >= to A (200)
- Step 4 ... >= to B (120)

Since the "equalTo" constraints have a Priority of less-than **required** they ***can be broken***... auto-layout will break `Step 2`, leaving 1, 3 and 4 satisfied, and RectC will be 200-pts wide.

Likewise, suppose RectA has a width of 160 and RectB has a width of 220...

Auto-layout will tell RectC's width to be:

- Step 1 ... equal to A (160)
- Step 2 ... equal to B (220)
- Step 3 ... >= to A (160)
- Step 4 ... >= to B (220)

Since the "equalTo" constraints have a Priority of less-than **required** they ***can be broken***... auto-layout will break `Step 1`, leaving 2, 3 and 4 satisfied, and RectC will be 220-pts wide.